# Entity Framework table with multiple optional one to one relationships

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

There are a few questions out there but none of them have been much help to me so I decided to ask my own.

I want to use Entity Framework code first to create a strange relationship. I have three entities (`Qualification`, `Test` and `Procedure`) that all have the option of having a document(s). I am attempting to store all the documents in one table. How do I configure the relationship between all these entities.

- `Qualification` has one to one optional `Document`
- `Test` has one to one optional `Document`
- `Procedure` has one to many optional `Documents`

`Document` has a required relationship to one `Qualification`, `Test` or `Procedure`.

```
public class Assessment
{
    public int AssessmentId { get; set; }
    //Other properties in Assessment
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}

public class Qualification
{
    public int QualificationId{ get; set; }
    //Other properties in Qualification
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}

public class Procedure
{
    public int ProcedureId { get; set; }
    //Other properties in Procedure
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    //Other properties in Document
    public Qualification Qualification { get; set; }
    public Assessment Assessment { get; set; }
    public Procedure Procedure { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Not sure what goes here, but this was not working 
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .HasOptional(d => d.Qualification).WithOptionalPrincipal(q => q.Document);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .HasOptional(d => d.Asssessment).WithOptionalPrincipal(q => q.Document);
}
```

When adding a migration I am getting an error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

I am not sure how to do this. I had a nullable int `DocumentId` in `Assessment` and `Qualification` but that will not work b/c `Procedure` can hold a collection so `Document` must hold the Id. Does `Document` hold a nullable Id for each possible parent? Help please.

Answer (score 2):

In your mappings you set `Document` as principal, but in reality it is the dependent. So you should change your mappings to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
    .HasRequired(d => d.Qualification)
    .WithOptionalDependent(q => q.Document);

modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
    .HasRequired(d => d.Asssessment)
    .WithOptionalDependent(q => q.Document);
```

Comment: Doesn't the `HasRequired` there mean that the document needs both a `Qualification` and an `Assessment`? Does nothing need to be done for `Procedure` and its optional one to many?

Comment: It helps EntityFramework to define the principal end. Generally nothing has to be done if you rely on [conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) nothing has to be done to configure relattionships. But you can olso configure it like `modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasRequired(m => m.Procedure).WithMany(m => m.Documents);`

Comment: In a general One-to-One relationship the Primary key of the child is a foreign key to the parent. Since I am using a database generated integer as the primary key in the parent will that cause primary key conflicts in `Document`? if `Qualification` `Assessment` are both the first in the database with a key of 1 and a `Document` is added for both is that going to be an issue?

Comment: @JaredStroeb, yes it is going to cause an issue. PK should be different on parents. Because, in this situation, if you add `Document` `Id` of which is 1, it will belong to both `Qualification` and 'Assesment'. In such scenarious, You have to make `Document` principal, or you have to generate Ids in a such manner that they do not overlap