# Entity Framework code first, one table with two (or multiple) one-to-one relationship to other tables

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-core

I have two classes, `Student` and `Staff`, both of them contain a field `Address`. So, there will be 1-to-1 relationship between `Student` and `Address` and 1-to-1 relationship between `Staff` and `Address`. I'm having trouble defining the relationship.

I've tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasOne(student => student.Address)
                    .WithOne(stdAddress => stdAddress.Student)
                    .HasForeignKey<Address>(stdAddress => stdAddress.StudentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>().HasOne(staff => staff.Address)
                    .WithOne(Address => Address.Staff)
                    .HasForeignKey<Address>(Address => Address.StaffId);
```

But when I try to migrate, I got error (This actually work, clear your db completely!)

Then I did some search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626581/entity-framework-table-with-multiple-optional-one-to-one-relationships).

However, when I try this code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                    .HasRequired(a => a.Student)
                    .WithOptionalDependent(s => s.Address);
```

I got a red line under HasRequired and no quick fix for it.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493229/multiple-yet-mutually-exclusive-foreign-keys-is-this-the-way-to-go) talking about using an extra table to achieve it, but I try to avoid this way.

Also, another solution I could think of is, make an abstract class called `Person`, and let student and staff inherited it, and map 1-to-1 from `Person` to `Address`. But this will be the backup plan, and I prefer to use Fluent API(right?) way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, but one of them should be null

Comment: Post please your classes for `Student` and `Staff`. This should be done automatically by EF.

Comment: The second attempt is wrong (EF6 syntax). What error are you getting with the first attempt (which should work IMO)?

Comment: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Address_Staffs_StaffId". The conflict occurred in database "WebProject", table "dbo.Staffs", column 'ID'.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak I've already created those three tables in db with EF, but can't sort out the relationship. Currently, I'm having a one-to-one relationship between `Student` and `Address`, but when I try to add one-to-one between `Staff` and `Address`, I got error

Comment: Make sure both `StudentId` and `StaffId` properties in `Address` are nullable.

Comment: @IvanStoev, something like this?
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                        .HasOptional(a => a.Student)
                        .HasOptional(a => a.Staff)
                        .HasKey(a => a.Id);

Comment: Can you please give an example? That one got syntax error or some errors

Comment: No, I meant using nullable *types*, e.g. `int?`. And use the initial (correct) fluent configuration (`HasOne` / `WithOne`).

Comment: @IvanStoev, both ID are `int` type

Comment: Then make them `int?` in `Address` class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you, what do you mean by make them `int`? They are `int` already. They are `int` in `Address` as well

Comment: I have some data in address table already. Could the error be caused by this? address is 1-to-1 with student, atm

Comment: @IvanStoev, I finally get what do you mean. I added a `?` to the int, and its all solved!