# Multiple optional one-to-one relations where one (any) of them is required

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, one-to-one

I checked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39626581/4934172) and other related questions, but couldn't find a working solution for my case.

So, I have 3 entities, `PrintingMethod`, `PrintingSubMethod`, and `PrintPricing`. The rules are:

- `PrintingMethod` has a collection of `PrintingSubMethod`. >> No problem with that.
- `PrintingMethod` ***can have*** zero or one `PrintPricing`.
- Each `PrintingSubMethod` ***must have*** one `PrintPricing`.
- Each `PrintPricing` ***must be*** linked with *either* a `PrintingMethod` *or* a `PrintingSubMethod`.

Here's the first two entities:

```vb
Public Class PrintingMethod
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property SupportsAdditionalColors As Boolean

    Public Overridable Property SubMethods As ICollection(Of PrintingSubMethod)
    Public Overridable Property AdditionalColorPricing As PrintPricing
End Class


Public Class PrintingSubMethod
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property PrintingMethodId As Integer

    <ForeignKey("PrintingMethodId")>
    Public Overridable Property ParentMethod As PrintingMethod

    Public Overridable Property Pricing As PrintPricing
End Class
```

And here's an illustration of the third one:

```vb
Public Class PrintPricing
    Public Property Id As Integer

    <ForeignKey("LinkedSubMethod")>
    Public Property SubMethodId As Integer

    <ForeignKey("LinkedMethod")>
    Public Property MethodId As Integer

    Public Overridable Property LinkedSubMethod As PrintingMethodCode
    Public Overridable Property LinkedMethod As PrintingMethod
End Class
```

So, is this possible to achieve using DataAnnotations or Fluent API? If not please feel free to suggest alternatives.

Notes:

- Irrelevant fields and DataAnnotations were removed for brevity.
- I'm using Entity Framework 6.0.
- Although my code is in VB, any C# answer is welcomed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship graph would look something like this, if I read your question right:

```
PrintingMethod       [1:n]  PrintingSubMethod
PrintingMethod    [0..1:1]  PrintPricing   
PrintingSubMethod [0..1:1]  PrintPricing
```

It's worth noting that a pure one to one relationship is not possible because the principal entity must always appear first (without the dependent entity existing which defeats the `1:1` constraint we're after). So a `1:1` in practice tends to be a one-to-zero-or-one-relationship.

> Each `PrintingSubMethod` must have one `PrintPricing`

So enforcing this rule would require you to handle it at some other layer.

---

```
public class PrintPricing 
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // You may want to uncomment the "navigation" properties, 
    // but I'm going to leave it commented so you know this is
    // not required for it to establish the relationship correctly, 
    // because this class represents the principal end of the relationship
    // public virtual PrintingMethod Method { get; set; }
    // public virtual PrintingSubMethod SubMethod { get; set; }
}

public class PrintingMethod 
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [ForeignKey("Pricing")] // foreign keys go on the dependent ends for 0:1 relationships
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PrintingSubMethod> SubMethods { get; set; }

    public virtual PrintPricing Pricing { get; set; }
}

public class PrintingSubMethod
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [ForeignKey("Pricing")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual PrintingMethod Method { get; set; }

    public virtual PrintPricing Pricing { get; set; }
}
```

You may also manually define foreign keys for the `PrintingMethod [1:n] PrintingSubMethod` relationship if you'd like, but EF is smart enough to figure that by itself, so that's optional. I personally prefer defining foreign keys manually.

Comment: You are correct about the graph, and I have no problem enforcing that rule at another layer. Still not sure how to implement your suggested solution though. I'm new to EF actually, so would be great if you elaborate on how to implement this *preferably using DataAnnotations where possible*. Thank you.

Comment: The part I care about is how to create two 0-1 relations to the same table. Because the way I know *using DataAnnotations* is by making the `FK` in the target table the `PK` as well.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I've added some code. The key is to add the foreign key to the dependent end, not the principal end. I haven't tried running it, so feel free to make edits :)

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for your effort. Okay, I tried your code *with nullable FK in `PrintingMethod`*, and got [this model diagram](https://s2.postimg.org/f47104wwp/image.png) *(not sure why it says 1-n!)* also when uncommenting the navigation properties, I get [this error](https://s2.postimg.org/44ltoplyx/error.png)

Comment: On a different note, before seeing your solution I worked on [something](https://codepaste.net/iytr3t#), which generated [this model diagram](https://s2.postimg.org/efy6gydjt/md2.png). It seems to work, but I'm not so confident about it though. I would appreciate it if you have a look on it and let me know if something is wrong with it and whether or not it's a better approach *if you can*. Thanks again :)

Comment: Oops I made a silly mistake: For 1:1 relationships both ends need to be candidate keys. Fixed it now. Your solution looks good to me as well (though I must admit I barely know any VB).